# bugzilla mail format when Edited bug is sent

Tags: perl, bugzilla

I am working on some mail formats related things. We have bugzilla installed at our end.
The issue is that when we try to edit the Bug Details and submit the same the mail format send to user on Outlook is quite disformatted.

Can anybody provide any hint from which file we can try to change the Mailformats

Answer (score 7):

For Bugzilla 4.2+ you need to look at the \template\en\default\email\bugmail*.tmpl files

For previous version look at \template\en\default\email\newchangedmail.txt.tmpl

In all cases Bugzilla is using http://www.template-toolkit.org/ as the templating engine.

See also: http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/4.2/en/html/cust-templates.html

Comment: Thanks Allen..that Helped ...Pardon me as i forget to reply this.